# Keycloak 18 +Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I want to use Keycloak 18 with my Spring boot 2.7.2 version. I can run & config Keycloak in a docker container (bitnami/keycloak:18), and finally I've got token by Postman. And then I tried to configure Spring boot by https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak . When I start SB I've got an error:
Failed to load URLs from http://localhost:48080/auth/realms/XXX/.well-known/openid-configuration
java.lang.Exception: Not Found

where XXX is an existing realm.

I think so something is changed in Keycloak 18.

Has somebody a working example with Spring boot & keycloak?

thx
Zamek

Comment: Need to remove `auth` from all URLs with keycloak served by quakus (Keycloak 18). Also, your tutorial is outdated: keycloak adapters are deprecated. An alternative for OpenID resource servers (Rest APIs): https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found it:
In application.properties I used

`keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:48080/auth`
but it needs
`keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:48080`